# ServerSocket.h and ServerException.h not found C++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, header

So I was writing some socket programming in C++. I'm new to the concept in general. I was following [this tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue74/tougher.html), but when I go to compile it, my compiler g++ says the header files are not found. I'm on linux (Netrunner 14 Frontier), so I updated all my headers but I still get the error. Is there any way to fix this? If not, any recommendations for how to do socket programming in linux?

Comment: his tutorial links off to them.

Comment: You are following the wrong tutorial. Use one which only uses standard linux [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are not part of the Linux system. If you look at the bottom of the page, it says:

```
The following files make up our example:
```

Beneath that line is a list of links to other files / dependencies, including those ones.